# How can I prove this implicit derivative always negative?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I would like to show that $t$ decreases as $k$ increases if $t$ is constrainted such that
$$\begin{align*}
f=-\alpha Ae^{-\alpha t}-\beta Be^{-\beta t} +k(A+B)e^{-kt}=0
\end{align*}$$
where
$$\begin{align*}
A&=\frac{k(\alpha-c)}{(\alpha-\beta)(k-\alpha)}\\
B&=-\frac{k(\beta-c)}{(\alpha-\beta)(k-\beta)}
\end{align*}$$
$t$, $\alpha$, $\beta$, $c$, $k$ are all positive real numbers.

By implicit differentation, the rate of change of $t$ wrt. $k$ would be
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{dt}{dk}&=-\frac{-\alpha\frac{dA}{dk}e^{-\alpha t}-\beta\frac{dB}{dk}e^{-\beta t}+(A+B) e^{-kt}+\left(\frac{dA}{dk}+\frac{dB}{dk}\right)ke^{-kt}-kt(A+B)e^{-kt}}{-\alpha^2 Ae^{-\alpha t}-\beta^2 Be^{-\beta t} +k^2(A+B)e^{-kt}} \\
&=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}/\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}
\end{align*}$$

Plots of $t$ and $\frac{dt}{dk}$ are as belows.
[image: Plots of $t$ and $\frac{dt}{dk}$]

I have proved that $\;\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\vert_{f=0}\;$ is always negative. But $\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}$ is difficult to be bound $<0$.

Although I can prove $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}=0$, it seems impossible to check $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial k^2}>0$ either.

This question seems to require some genius touch and **I will accept useful comments as answers (no need full answers)**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a brief side note, $A$, $B$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ emerge from solving ODEs by Laplace Transform.